# C# code generation / removing redundant code

Tags: c#, templates, code-generation

I have some simple code in a class:

```
private ITemplate _content1 = null;
[TemplateContainer(typeof(ContentContainer))]
public ITemplate Content1
{
    get
    { return _content1; }
    set
    { _content1 = value; }
}
```

I need about 15 of these content containers. I could just copy and paste this block 15 times and change the number, but there must be a better way. Can anyone suggest a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Could you make Content1 contain ITemplate items?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do - any chance of adding some context to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[TemplateContainer(typeof(ContentContainer))]
public ITemplate Content1
{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Note that this is only available as of C# 3.

Comment: I'm using C# 2.0 and this works for me. I double-checked my project's properties and it's definitely using 2.0. Are you sure about the 3.0 requirement?

Comment: 2.0 .Net project != C# 2.0. If it compiles you're fine.

Comment: Crazy and awesome at the same time. It works, so I'll use it - I can deal with 2 lines per property. Thanks!

Comment: It's a feature of the compiler in VS2008. You get the features regardless of the targeted framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property (prop) Snippet (snippets are native to visual studio).

Either modify the snippet (it is a simple xml file), or create a new one for your task.

ReSharper has a easier way, called code templates.

Or, generate the properties you need with a t4 script.  But that is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an collection of containers such as List for example? It seems that the only think you're changing is the integer index, using a List would make sense.